# Как заключить значение переменной в кавычки|апострофы

Tags: linux, bash

Есть код

```
#!/bin/bash

read commandName #Название

read command #Команда


alas="alias ${commandName}=${command}"

echo "${alas}" >> ~/.bashrc

. ~/.bashrc #Перезагрузка /.bashrc
```

который должен добавлять алис и перезагружать /.bashrc.
Вопрос можно ли как то заключить вторую часть алиса в кавычки, апострофы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть одинарные (`'`) и двойные (`"`) кавычки. Разница в том, что если внешние кавычки двойные, то переменные (`$variable` или `${variable}`) внутри них раскроются и подставится значение переменной. Если внешние кавычки одинарные - подставится имя переменной.
То есть вот так:

```sh
sheridan$ a="1"
sheridan$ b="$a"
sheridan$ c='$a'
sheridan$ echo $b
1
sheridan$ echo $c
$a
```

Далее, двойные кавычки внутри можно экранировать обратным слешем (`\"`)

Следовательно вам нужно сделать так:

```sh
sheridan$ commandName="ls_my"
sheridan$ command="ls"
sheridan$ my_alias="alias ${commandName}=\"${command}\""
sheridan$ echo $my_alias
alias ls_my="ls"
```

Апострофы (`` ` ``) в bash - совсем про другое. То что внутри апострофов - выполнится и вернет результат:

```sh
sheridan$ a=`uname`
sheridan$ echo $a
Linux
```

Но я предпочитаю вместо апострофов использовать конструкцию `$()`:

```sh
sheridan$ a=$(uname)
sheridan$ echo $a
Linux
```

Comment: *однотипные кавычки внутри можно экранировать слешем* — во-первых: [обратным слэшем (backslash)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратная_косая_черта), во-вторых: нельзя для одинарных кавычек. `a=' \' '` — синтаксически неверная конструкция.

Comment: *Апострофы (`\``) в bash* — во-первых: не [апостроф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Апостроф), а [обратный апостроф (backquote)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Машинописный_обратный_апостроф), во-вторых: [работает (наряду с `$(...)`) в любой posix-совместимой оболочке](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) (т.е., не является чем-то уникальным для программы bash, как может показаться из ваших слов).

Comment: Прошу прощения, если выглядит чем-то уникальным. Не было даже мысли так выставить. Ну и апостроф я называю апострофом потому как апостроф называю одинарной кавычкой и считаю, что не нужно вносить лишние сущности в данном случае (не в ответе на не-типографский вопрос) :)